# How to count negatives?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I wrote this code and the output is not coming as expected. The function returns the negatives recursively. But it is not doing returning what it should be.

```
size_t recursive_x(stack<int> mystack){
        int count=0;
        if(!mystack.empty()){
            if(mystack.top()<0){
                count+=1;
            }
            mystack.pop();
            count+=recursive_x(mystack);
        }cout<<count<<endl;
        return count;
}
int main(){

    stack<int> mystack;
    mystack.push(9);
    mystack.push(-2);
    mystack.push(-2);
    mystack.push(1);
    mystack.push(-3);
    mystack.push(-1);
    mystack.push(99);
    mystack.push(-1);
    mystack.push(1);
    mystack.push(1);
    recursive_x(mystack);
 }
```

The output should be 5 but it is coming like this:

Output:

```
0
0
1
2
2
3
4
4
5
5
5
```

Comment: You aren't even calling the function.

Comment: Sorry forgot to write it in here.

Comment: Read this: http://sscce.org/ and then update your question. I also suggest changing your title to something more descriptive; what you have could describe almost every question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each recursive call will print the result.
You just need to move the print command to the main:

```
size_t recursive_x(stack<int> mystack){
        int count=0;
        if(!mystack.empty()){
            if(mystack.top()<0){
                count+=1;
            }
            mystack.pop();
            count+=recursive_x(mystack);
        }
        return count;
}
int main(){

    stack<int> mystack;
    mystack.push(9);
    mystack.push(-2);
    mystack.push(-2);
    mystack.push(1);
    mystack.push(-3);
    mystack.push(-1);
    mystack.push(99);
    mystack.push(-1);
    mystack.push(1);
    mystack.push(1);
    cout<<recursive_x(mystack)<<endl;
 }
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Is there an another way to do this without writing cout statement in main.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do call the function, the output is exactly what I would expect.

The display shows the number of negative numbers on the stack at the point where

```
cout<<count<<endl;
```

is invoked.

It is invoked first for the innermost recursion, because you make your recursive call before doing any output for the current recursion.

```
count+=recursive_x(mystack);
    }cout<<count<<endl;
```

If you just want the output `5`, you could print the result returned from your initial call

```
int finalCount = recursive_x(mystack);
cout<<finalCount<<endl;
```

and remove the output in `recursive_x()`.

Comment: So where should I invoke this statement?

Comment: @user4032883 you never invoke a statement. You invoke a function. If it returns something and you want to store it. Do `c = recursive_x(mystack)`, then print `c` to see if it is what you want.

Comment: Updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @taocp It didn't work.

Comment: Eric J. I am not sure what are you trying to say?